# Setup/Install project checks for a previously installed project before installing?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, verification

Is there a way for my setup/installer poject to check that another program is installed on the machine before proceeding with the install process? I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer supports [launch conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f09xywha%28VS.80%29.aspx).  You can use the Component ID of the program to determine if it's installed.  Use MSI Spy to get the Component ID of a program.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, some programs are listed as pre-requisites in the setup project.  For example, all the .Net Frameworks, SQL Server Compact, Windows Installer 3 etc.  If you check these, you can actually have your app prompt to download the missing files.